# CSS border-image not displaying on iOS10

Tags: ios, css, ipad, ios10

Since iOS10, there seems to be a problem with the CSS border-image attributes.

I used to work with something like this:

`border-image: url('data:image/png;base64,somedata') 30 30 30 stretch;`

However, since updating to iOS10 on iPad (and I would guess on iPhone as well), the border-image is no longer visible, leaving it transparent.

This happens with Safari and Chrome browsers on iPad.

Here's a fiddle so you can see how it behaves on iPad vs computer: 
https://jsfiddle.net/g99y6pg3/1/

I also tried with a `border-image: url(filename.png)` instead of data:image/png, but got the same result.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need set property 'border-color' = 'white'

Comment: Wow, it worked instantly, thank you very much!  It's weird how, and why, this would have changed with a new release of iOS, both for Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Why isn't this mentioned anywhere [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image) doesn't even have it flagged as a known issue. Thank you.